# Struts2 Load ALL values in a s:select tag into a HashMap in the action class

Tags: forms, struts2, hashmap, populate

I have researched enough on this topic sans any luck :-(

My requirement is to load a HashMap that is declared in the action class from the jsp form that has a s:select tag.

Here is my action class

```
public class AttributeAction extends ActionSupport {
    private HashMap<String, String> lstAttrTypesHashMap;
    public void setLstAttrTypesHashMap(HashMap<String, String> lstAttrTypesHashMap) {
        this.lstAttrTypesHashMap = lstAttrTypesHashMap;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getLstAttrTypesHashMap() {
        return lstAttrTypesHashMap;
    }

    public String renderPageAction() {
        lstAttrTypesHashMap.put("ENTRY1", "VALUE1");
        lstAttrTypesHashMap.put("ENTRY2", "VALUE2");
        lstAttrTypesHashMap.put("ENTRY3", "VALUE3");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String searchAction() {
        logger.info("***************************************");
        logger.info("searchAction Started ...");
        logger.info("a.getType() = [" + a.getType() + "]");
        logger.info("getLstAttrTypesHashMap() = [" + getLstAttrTypesHashMap() + "]");
        return SUCCESS;
    } 
}
```

here is how I show the drop down in the jsp

```
<s:select 
  key="a.type" 
  label="Select Object Type" 
  name="a.type" 
  list="lstAttrTypesHashMap" />
```

Here is the struts.xml

```
<action name="attributeSearch" method="searchAction" class="com.frk.gid.action.AttributeAction">
    <result name="success">/AttributeResult.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/AttributeInput.jsp</result>
</action>
    <action name="attributeRender" method="renderPageAction" class="com.frk.gid.action.AttributeAction">
    <result name="success">/AttributeInput.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When the above jsp loads, I can see that the drop down is **populated** fine. However when I submit it back to the action, i can only see the **selected value (a.type)** . The hashmap happens to be null. Is there anything else I need to do to get this HashMap loaded? My understanding was Struts2 would automatically load the HashMap from the dropdown on submit - apparently not ... appreciate any input !!!!

Comment: S2 will send only the selected value from the select as per HTML standard as select is nothing but in end an HTML select tag.

Comment: Why do you need the Hashmap back? If you want the dropdown list values to be same when something is changed you can change list="lstAttrTypesHashMap" to list="getLstAttrTypesHashMap". Or if you're doing something else, you can iterate over the hashmap to assign values to hidden values.

Comment: As @batbaatar said use hidden variable or put save it in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for your responses !

Finally I decided to go with passing Hidden variables and it worked like a charm.

Also, I had complex types like Map>, I had to write my own Type Converter to convert from and to String.